# $ a + a^2 = 90 $. Need hint.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

From trig text. Am supposed to find complementary angles $a$ and $a^2$.
Tried completing the square, got

$(a + 1/2)^2 = 361/4$.

Stuck. Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the square root of both sides, in the equation you got after completing the square.

As columbus8myhw [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330006/a-a2-90-need-hint/1330010#comment2702410_1330010), remember to put a $\pm$ sign.

Note that $19^2=361$

Comment: And remember to put in a $\pm$ sign; $X^2=Y^2$ implies $X=\pm Y$. (Because $Y$ isn't the _only_ square root of $Y^2$ here...)

Comment: How did you get that link to the comment?

Comment: @TonyK The timestamp is a link to the comment.

Comment: Thank you. That would never have occurred to me!